# Как в командной сроке вывести на печать результат выполнения другой команды?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

Мне нужно в строку с командой подставить результат выполнения другой команды. Например, на псевдокоде это могло бы выглядеть так:

```
docker run --rm -v ${pwd}/sql:/flyway/sql -v ${pwd}/conf:/flyway/conf flyway/flyway migrate
```

Данная конструкция не работает. Мне надо заметь `${pwd}` на что-то корректное.

Comment: Если команда выводит единственную строку и ее подставить, то вместо `${pwd}` написать саму команду, заключенную в обратные апострофы `\`команда\`` или воспользоваться xargs

Comment: а ещё есть переменная окружения `PWD`, [специфицированная стандартом posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03).

Comment: @Mike, советовать лучше хорошее — `$( ... )`. вполне [posix-корректно](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03). вряд ли ведь сейчас кто-то пользуется оболочками, игнорирующими требования posix (типа как в дремучих версиях sun/solaris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo pwd = ${pwd}
```

> pwd =

```
echo pwd = `pwd`
```

> pwd = /root

```
echo pwd = $(pwd)
```

> pwd = /root

```
pwd=/root; echo pwd = $pwd
```

> pwd = /root

```
pwd=/root; echo pwd = ${pwd}
```

> pwd = /root